# boost::format gives different results than round

Tags: c++, math, boost, rounding

I would like to understand why

```
double nbr = 102262.5;

boost::format("%.0f") % nbr;
```

gives `102262` while `round(102262.5)` gives `102263.0`

If we take another example value `34087.5`

```
boost::format("%.0f") % nbr
```

gives `34088` and `round(34087.5)` gives the same `34088`

Does it mean round implements a more sophisticated algorithm to ensure the nearest while format or printf does not?

Comment: What do you get with `round(nbr)`? Different isn't the same.

Comment: I get the same result with round(nbr) as when using the literal value.

Comment: are you refering to `std::round` or `boost::round`? Anyhow they both use the same rounding, which makes it even more surprising that `boost::format` works differently

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a thing called "round half to even" or "round half to odd" ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)).

This is a rule to reduce the bias of rounding errors and 
`boost::format` seems to implement such a strategy.
Essentially this is to round the tie-breaking cases (such as 1.5 or 2.5) up and down equally often in a deterministic way (depending on the number itself). If one would always round up or round down these cases all, a statistical bias could be introduced by rounding. 
The latter is the more "classical" way of rounding which seems to be implemented by `round`.

Note that the strategy implemented by `boost::format` (round half to even) corresponds to the default rounding mode in the IEEE 754 standard.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so effectively, they do not work the same way. And boost::format's algorithm is more sophisticated.

Comment: Different. Different rounding stragegies work best for different domains/applications. It's never good to assume any particular rounding if not documented, and rarely a reason to expect different libraries to use the same.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, if you want round half to even behavior in C++ without relying on Boost, you could call the C++ standard library function `std::rint` which is available if your compiler supports C++11 (or later) C++ standard.

If you're using a pre-C++11 compiler which supports calling C standard library functions, you could call one of the C standard library functions `rintf`, `rint`, or `rintl`, depending on which floating-point type you are using.